# Magento 2 Create observer on customer create, with custom module

Tags: magento2, module, customer, custom

I want to create an observer in my custom module which called when new customer create and delete.

In my custom module i want to add custom data when customer created and delete custom data when customer deleted even its created from admin or imported.

How can i achieve this functionality.

Thanks.

Comment: i want to perform some action on customer save.

Answer (score 4):

For **Save** You can use this event `customer_save_after` when triggered you will get following below data.

```
customer_save_after => data_object(object), customer(object)
```

In Observer you can get customer data by

```
$observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
```

For **Delete** You can use

```
customer_delete_after => data_object(object), customer(object)
```

**Note:** You can use before or after as per your requirement.

Comment: I search for events but I don't find same event. there are other events you can check here : https://blog.mdnsolutions.com/magento-2-list-of-all-events/

Comment: This events are available. Did you try using this event?

Comment: yes i am trying but still no success. i tried with "adminhtml_customer_save_after" and "customer_save_after_data_object" events.

Comment: use `customer_save_after` event it should work.

Comment: could you please post whole example.?

Comment: do we need to create events.xml file in "etc/adminhtml" or "etc/frontend" or "etc" folder?

Right now I am trying to add customer from admin side.

Comment: it depends where you want. If you want in both the sides to work. You can create in `etc/events.xml`. But if you want in specific  are to work in then create in those specific area.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87069/discussion-between-utsav-gupta-and-priyank).